# How can I see approximately when points were awarded?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, sorting, timestamps

Often I'll notice a change in my rep without a corresponding comment from the awarder (or detractor, as the case may be) and as my list of actions grows, it's harder and harder to see why someone might've awarded me points. Is there some way to look at point awards themselves chronologically, or even just "show me points awarded in the last day" kind of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the envelope at the top of the screen to see the most recent changes in reputation. You can filter up to 30 days at a time.

For ordered day-size granularity, visit https://stackoverflow.com/reputation.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Once I get to 15 rep maybe I'll come back and vote this up. :P